# AWS EC2 - syncronizing two instances between two region for replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What would be the best way in AWS to maintain redundancy between two EC2 instance on two different region ? My client want to be sure that he will loose no data if something goes wrong in the main region dc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look at the official AWS guides [Cross-Region DR for EC2 with CloudEndure](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/configuring-cross-region-dr-of-your-amazon-ec2-workloads-with-cloudendure/), [as well as multi-region application solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/creating-a-multi-region-application-with-aws-services-part-2-data-and-replication/).

Please consider the following when you design the synchronization between EC2 instances across regions:

- Availability
- Consistency
- Partition tolerance.

In particular, in the second AWS guide you can find information on using AWS Backup to save and store EC2 instances as AMI images.

Furthermore, if you have a database solution in place with data that is accessed (some variant of CRUD operations) *from both EC2* instances, the design will be more intricate. Check out the topic "Spanning relational databases across regions" in the second AWS guide.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, yet robust approach would be to use [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/features/).

[Create an EFS file system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-getting-started.html) in your primary region and [set-up replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-replication.html) to a secondary region. Then move all data from EC2 storage (i.e. EBS) to EFS using an appropriate mount point. Repeat on EC2 instance in secondary region.